# Issue With Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, kendo-ui

I am trying to get the value from the Kendoui Checkbox but without success so far.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="telephonyeq1" name="telephonychk[]" class="k-checkbox telephonycb">
```

The script

```
<script>
    if($('#telephonyeq1').is(":checked"))
        {
        var telephonycb = "true"
        }
        else {
        var telephonycb = "false"
        }
</script>
```

when i am POST the data through AJAX i am always receiving value as "False", even if it's checked or unchecked.

```
Telephony: false
```

And the Ajax

```
        $("#save").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/test",
                method: "post",
                data: { 
                     .....
                    "telephonycb": telephonycb,
                    "internetcb": internetcb,
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
                        printSuccessMsg(data.success);

                    } else{
                        printErrorMsg(data.error);
                    }
                }

            }); 

        }); 
        function printErrorMsg (msg) {
            ......
        }
        function printSuccessMsg (msg) {
            $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").html('');
            $(".print-error-msg").css('display','none');
            $(".print-success-msg").css('display','block');
            $("h5 span").html(
                '<br /><h5><strong>Incident Description</strong>
                .......
                '</code><br /><h5><strong>Impact on Services</strong></h5>Telephony: <code>' + telephonycb + '</code> Service Issues <code>' + telephony.value() + '</code> - Affected Users: <code>' + telephonyaffected.value() +
                '</code><br />Internet: <code>' + internetcb + '</code> Service Issues <code>' + internet.value() + '</code> - Affected Users: <code>' + internetaffected.value() +
                ......
                );

        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Show us your full code: including the ajax

Comment: Also where is the code you have shown now? It needs to be in an event or at the end of the page, but it will only register what the checkbox was at load time

Comment: Thanks for your respones, how i can dynamically change the value on javascript variable?

Comment: just do `"telephonycb":$('#telephonyeq1').is(":checked")`

Comment: Thanks Carsten, works like a charm

Comment: @tphil No problem, happy to help

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update the line inside the ajax

```
"telephonycb": (($('#telephonyeq1:checked').length > 0) ? "true ": "false"),
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying is sending the value *telephonycb* through Ajax, it's always going to be false.

The script you have is executed only once at load time. If you want to keep the variable, you can add the function change so it updates the variable when you click the box.

Example:

```
$('#telephonyeq1').change(function(){
    if($('#telephonyeq1').is(":checked"))
        {
           var telephonycb = "true"
        }
        else {
           var telephonycb = "false"
        }
});
```